# Basic understanding of MS SQL Server terminology and tools

Tags: sql-server

I just installed Visual Studio 2015 Preview, and is my first time with MS SQL so there are some very basic stuff I need to clarify and internet is full of examples and information of too many different versions of SQL right.

What I want is to develop an application using SQL (localdb) on my dev machine, and change the connection string on publish to use an azure sql database.

These are the questions I'm having right now.

1. Microsoft Sql 2014 == Sql Server 7.0 ?

---

2. On Visual Studio (Servers add connection to database) if I type `(LocalDB)\v12.0` as server name it returns a error: 50 The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
   I'm pretty sure this used to work and now it doesnt.

`sqllocaldb info` returns :

```
MSSQLLocalDB
MyLocalDb (manually created by myself in command line)
ProjectsV12
```

---

3. Where can I expect to find Sql Management Studio (is installed) ? I tryed on start menu and lookin on explorer browsing relevenat folder but I can't found it.

Do I need to install separatelly? Here is what I have on installed programs:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Command Line Utilities
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Objects
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Objects (x64)
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Transact-SQL ScriptDom
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 T-SQL Language Service
Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - enu (14.0.41025.0)
Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types
Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types (x64)
Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2014
Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2014
```

*Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2014 is listed twice*
  and what's all this stuff anyway?

---

4. Should I better use localdb or express o what on my dev machine for MS Sql ? Is it ok to use Management Studio to work with the database? This is my first time with MS Sql, (used other SQL servers for several years) and I think I'm having problems understanding naming, connection string, versions, etc. A very basic guide of what is localdb and whats express and whats management studio (is it like the IDE for the DB?, like heidi ? will be really appreciated. And one normally go to find out how to solve problems like the one I'm having on #2.

Comment: This is a *Question and Answer* site (note the singular), not *Questions and Answers*. The general rule here is 1 question per post, rather than asking many as a tutorial.

Comment: @KenWhite I know, the 'single' question will be : can someone explain me the basics naming and versioning of MS SQL ? :D

Comment: :-) Um, no. We don't write tutorials here, I'm afraid. *Can someone teach me how to program in C?*  would also not be acceptable. :-)  And with your rep, you're not new here, so I shouldn't have to point you to the [help/dont-ask] : *Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.* They write entire books that serve as introductory text for SQL Server; there are several on Amazon that are quite good.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft Sql 2014 == Sql Server 7.0

Not at all. Use `SELECT @@VERSION` to tell.

> 2.

I don't know.

> Where can I expect to find Sql Management Studio (is installed) ?

VS does not come with SSMS. Download it separately. Use the free Express Edition or Developer Edition.

> Should I better use localdb or express

I have never used LocalDB. I don't see a problem with installing a real SQL Server (process: click next, next, next ...) and creating a database there.

That way you take LocalDB out of the picture. You don't have to understand id. SQL Server and SSMS are well documented.